# Run Python file from Unspecified Directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm running a python file named test.py . I have a folder in the same directory named Model. Inside Model I have several other folders (like UserMgmt, GPO, DNS etc) each containing different python programs. Now, I want to run python program from the UserMgmt or DNS or GPO folder based on the users choice. I've tried..

```
    foldername = raw_input('Enter foldername:');
    filename = raw_input('Enter filename:');
    from Model.foldername import filename;
```

But it is showing error 'Invalid Syntax'. I have to import the python files as I'll be using variables and functions from those files. But the python file and the path to the file is dependent on the user. How to import the python file in this scenario ?
Please Help...
Thank you in advance.

Comment: style comment ... python is not `c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use importlib or imp module

importlib will be good to import some module relative to current dir

```
import importlib
# foldername need to be in same dir with this script
foldername = raw_input('Enter foldername:')
# enter filename without .py for this case
filename = raw_input('Enter filename:')
test = importlib.import_module(foldername + '.' + filename)
# for example, foldername = 'GPO', filename = 'test'
# this will import GPO\test.py
```

if you wanna import some file from arbitrary path, you can use imp module

```
import imp
import os
# foldername can be from anywhere
foldername = raw_input('Enter foldername:')
# enter filename with .py for this case
filename = raw_input('Enter filename:')
test = imp.load_source(filename ,os.path.join(foldername, filename))
# for example, foldername = r'C:\NGO', filename = 'test.py'
```

Comment: The path is Model\GPO\test.py
How do I import from two directories down ?

Comment: you can do importlib.import_module('Model.GPO.test') or imp.load_source('test',os.path.join(r'path_to_Model\Model\GPO', 'test'))

Comment: It is showing error:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

But I checked, the file is present in the specified folder.

Comment: `import importlib;    
import imp;    
import os;    
def main(thelist):    
 foldername = thelist.pop(0);    
 filename = thelist.pop(0);    
 print foldername, filename;    
 test = imp.load_source(filename ,os.path.join(foldername, filename)); `

Comment: ^ This is the code for MachineController.py . This code is called from another python script test.py

Comment: `thelist=list();
thelist= ['Model', 'Baz', 'Arnab', 'password@123'];
import MachineController;
MachineController.main(thelist);
`

Comment: ^Code for test.py

Comment: The entire error msg is:
`Model Baz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    MachineController.main(thelist);
  File "/media/arnab/Storage/TISL/Identity_v2.0/SourceCode/ClientMachine/Controller/MachineController.py", line 8, in main
    test = imp.load_source(filename ,os.path.join(foldername, filename));
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: `imp.load_source('test',os.path.join(r'path_to_Model\Model\GP‌​O', 'test'))` ---It has to be test.py not test !! Like this `imp.load_source('test.py',os.path.join(r'path_to_Model\Model\GP‌​O', 'test.py'))`

Comment: oh ya, i just copy and paste, my mistake

Comment: you may accept the answer though if you found useful, there is a checkbox to the left  :)

Comment: Can it be done without using absolute path ? Just by using Relative path ? If we want to remove the `path_to_Model`

Comment: imp.load_source require full path, use importlib.import_module to load from relative to current path. Or what you can do is get the path_to_Model with `os.path.dirname(__file__)` , this will get the directory to current py script

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the variables with this syntax.

In your code you are literally importing a filename from foldername module.

Try using following code:

```
exec("from Model.{} import {}".format(foldername, filename))
```

Comment: What's wrong with `importlib.import_module()` ? Hint : there are **very** few things that _really_ requires using `exec`.

Comment: I didn't say it's wrong. I just propose a different solution.

Comment: Then why propose a basically unsafe solution when there are safer ones ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: We are learning all the time :) 
I was not aware that there are better solutions.

Comment: @woockashek Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to dynamic imports, [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/importlib.html) is your friend. But if you only want to execute a given python *script* based on it's path you can simply use `os.system()` or `execfile()`.

Comment: NB: note that `execfile` is barely safer than `exec` so better to filter out user inputs.

Comment: I tried `importlib.import_module()` but when I use the filename, it says filename not found.
For instance I'm trying to run the main function in Baz.py
So, after import_module I tried `Baz.main()` ,
Error occurs:  global name 'Baz' is not defined .

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `__import__()` and if you use python2.7+ or 3.1+ it's better to use `exec` .

Comment: It's **never** "better" to use `exec`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers why not ?

Comment: because (almost)  everything you can do with `exec` and/or `eval` can be done in a cleaner, more maintainable and much much safer way.